# How to fix audio issues with Linux Mint Virginia Cinnamon?

Tags: linux-mint, audio

I just hooked my Zenbook up with the latest version of Mint (Virginia Cinnamon). 
I've not used a Linux distro before, and I heard would be a great transition from Windows.

Anyhow, as I'm going through the motions learning the UI, I got on YouTube to see what I could download, and, to my surprise, I couldn't hear any audio.

- I checked my volume to see if it was muted by chance.
- I put `alsamixer` in the terminal to see if the OS recognized my hardware.
- I even rebooted my system several times after each of these changes, and I still have not had any luck.

I haven't checked any root files because I don't want to mess anything else up if possible.

Any tips?

Comment: There seems to be 40 distinct models currently in Asus's Zenbook range - which model exactly? And did `alsamixer` indicate your hardware was recognized, or not? Please *edit your question* to answer the questions above, and to show the output of `lspci -d ::0403 -nnv` on your system.